# build/rebuild throws System.ExecutionEngineException error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have two projects in my solution and I am connected to TFS. Whenever I build/rebuild the solution, my VS2015 crashes before completing the build.

The error on debugging in a new vs2015 instance is:

```
'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll
```

What could be the possible causes to this error and what ways could I diagnose this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try a Google search on ` 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll` ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and/or rebooting your machine? 
I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967044/system-executionengineexception-failure don't know if it'll help

Comment: Google pointed to possibilities of  missing TFS bindings. Repair did not help. I did a un-install and re-install and it works now.