# Calling a Function from a Method crashes my App (due to "ExecutionEngineException in unknown Module")?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime-error

I had something happen today that I had never experienced before.

By way of background, I had simply moved a fairly small block of code out of a method and put the code in a function the method could call.  As soon as I ran the app, I'd reach the nethod without a problem (as usual).  But when it came time for the method to call the function - the moment the processing entered the function... the entire app would crash!

For what it’s worth, at least one of the times I reached the function, this error was triggered:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module

That message was new to me, but research seems to indicate that it's a fairly difficult error to try to track down because (if I understand this correctly) the error may have nothing to do with the point in the processing where the error is triggered.  (Please correct me if I'm wrong about that.)

As soon as I removed the code from the function and simply placed it back into the method, everything was fine; no more error.

If it helps for you to know this, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 8 for this project.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: The runtime may `Environment.FailFast()` in some cases due to unresolvable errors, killing your process.  For example, if there is an exception while restoring an `AsyncLocal`, the runtime can't resume your async code and will just crash (here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c7253b133feefa26d3bb5f07ddcd7563efd511b4/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ExecutionContext.cs#L435). For more specific advice, post a minimal example.

Comment: While `System.ExecutionEngineException` is deprecated, there are some unresolvable errors in native code that would still log or throw one; https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fruntime+COR_E_EXECUTIONENGINE&type=code&p=1

Comment: And VS might get confused about how the error should be displayed https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63244#issuecomment-1360616019

Comment: This exception is thrown when there is an internal error in the execution engine of the CLR and might arise from diverse reasons. Did you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967044/System-executionEngineException-failure)?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: Throwing an `ExecutionEngineException` in .NET 8 (OP uses it) is really weird since the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.executionengineexception?view=net-8.0) state *The runtime no longer raises this exception so this type is obsolete.* Your Github link is useful, thanks.

Comment: I agree with @JeremyLakeman and this exception might well be thrown because of an `Environment.FailFast()` call. Do you have any assertions (`Debug.Assert()` e.g.) in a relevant part of your code? A failing `Assert()` will probably raise an `Environment.FailFast()`.

Comment: I haven't used Debug.Assert() in this Class.  My earlier research did find that this Exception is deprecated; but I did get the Error.  My Method was calling a boolean Function that would loop through a List<string> to see if a particular string was in the List.  I probably should have just used Linq in the Method, but again, I never even got to run the Function because the crash would occur.  Fwiw, one of your links helped me to reach this 2023 note: "This is a result of bad interaction between Visual Studio and the runtime- there is no exception, but the UI makes it look like there is."

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example without personal privacy?

Comment: Minxin, it was pretty basic.  Method called Function with 2 params; a List of Models and a string.  If this is relevant, the Model has about 10 properties; one of which is a List<string>.  No problem handling this inside the Method, but moved to the Function and App crashed when I stepped past the Function's opening bracket.  Fwiw, there were times when I'd reach the Function, hover over the incoming params and see their values; whereas other times I'd reach that point, hover and get no feedback; perhaps a message indicating that the param values couldn't be evaluated. Code hadn't changed.

Comment: Do you get the error *only* when you debug the code in VS? Do you get it when you directly run the exe?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example or people will probably be reluctant to help.

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provide a complete simple console sample by updating the question will be better.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't keep a draft of the code that caused the error. Frustrated, I fixed it as I described and simply moved on.  I can try to post what I *believe* represents what *might* have been the problem at the time, but know this first: I began putting that together for you today by removing the code from the method I spoke of and placing it into a function.  I don't know why, but this time it WORKED.  So please know I'd be posting code that seemingly can't replicate the problem  I'll still do that if you want, but may need some help.  Please see next Comment when I'm able to post it.

Comment: Part 2: If you still want me to post the now un-problematic code... as a Stack newbie, I need to know how to post a code sample which will get linked to my original message. Minxin, I looked at the link you suggested.  It's really helpful as to how to *format* a message containing code, but it doesn't say how I post something that remains on the same 'thread' as my original message.  Obviously I can't do this just in a Comment.  Do I edit the old message to include the new code sample?  My apologies, but any directions on this would be welcome because I'm not finding this explained anywhere.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77998335/edit) your question and append your code to where your original post ends.